# Overriding background color

Tags: html, css

I've got question about CSS.

I've got 2 divs, one with `background-color: #000;` and second with transparent png file partly without background (so transparent), let's call it `background-image: url(images/scrolltotop.png);`.

What I want, is to override `background-color` with transparency from png file, so the background doesn't cover my png file. I'll give images to show you what i mean:

[image: transparent png file]

[image: that what it is without transparency]

[image: result]

and now image with the result I want to get (above) - with background from html style.

Is there any way to cover background-color with transparency?

[image]
[image]

edit: maybe this img will tell you more, what I want to do (above)

Comment: if the PNG is transparent, simply put a white background on the "scroll to top" div

Comment: but i don't want white background, want it to be transparent.

Comment: CSS Masks (webkit only I believe) may be able to accomplish this: http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking

Answer (score 1):

```
background-color: transparent;
```

Have you tried that?

**EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/FCXGu/3/

```
border-width: 20px;
border-image: url("//i.imgur.com/hg2Thfa.png") 20 stretch;
-moz-border-image: url("//i.imgur.com/hg2Thfa.png") 20 stretch;
-webkit-border-image: url("//i.imgur.com/hg2Thfa.png") 20 stretch;
```

It takes a moment to understand how this can work. The border of the image essentially acts like the "padding" as it is generally thicker than normal. You could thought just have the top of the border thick for your cutout in which case your code might look like:

```
 border-image: url("//i.imgur.com/hg2Thfa.png") 20 0 0 0 stretch;
```

This would mean the top border of your div, would use the top 20 pixels of the image you are using, and the rest of the image would just be used in the content area of your div. Either way, the effect you want can be achieved with border-image.

Is it the best way/only way? Probably not, but it is one way.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FCXGu/3/

I added a content area just to illustrate where everything is in this one: http://jsfiddle.net/FCXGu/4/

Without seeing your exact image, page, and usage I couldn't tell you the best way to create a png, use stretch vs repeat, etc. But border-image is pretty flexible. However it is does not work in ALL browsers. Just the good ones.

Comment: Yep doesnt help it. I'll show you what kind of effect I want to get (with edit)

Comment: Ahh. I see. Then no, the effect you want cannot be achieved with a png. It's hard to tell without knowing your exact application, but a CSS3 `border-image` might do what you want.

Comment: Hi. You can see what i want exactly to do in edit of question (image 4 with photo).

Comment: Well, if what you want to do is literally remove a piece of it from the edge like that, border-image can do it. http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/ is one of the better tutorials on border image and covers everything. Just make part of the image you use for the border transparent and it should work. Not supported in all browsers, so... there's that.

Comment: You mean i should do it by border-image:url(images/border.png) repeat? It'll be hard to do it when u can't use no-repeat which I didn't see tbh in CSS3 specs. I want it only once. My idea is to cut top lane within PS and margin with "-" to other background. Don't know how to do it other way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes you can do it without repeating. I'll make a fiddle with an example for you. It sort of depends on if you know where the cut out is going to be each time. Give me a second and I will make a png and a demo example.